# Best practices of Karma with AngularJS in Spring MVC project

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm currently working on a Spring MVC based project where I use AngularJS in front end. I want to use `Karma` for unit testing.

I would like to have a reference to get to know the best practices of Karma with AngularJS in Spring MVC project.

And it's great if anyone can tell **a way to get `karma` to test without getting all dependencies inside `node_modules` directory** in my project directory.